# How to integrate a function $f(x,y)=xy$ over a 2D planar polygon?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, greens-theorem

How do I integrate the above function over a simple planar polygon in the $z$-plane using Green's theorem? I'm unsure about how to derive the functions $P$ and $Q$ from

\begin{align}
\int\!\!\!\!\int_{\Omega} xy \,\,dxdy = \int\!\!\!\!\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \,\,dxdy = \oint_{\partial\Omega} P\ dx + Q \ dy
\end{align}

Comment: What are $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: @Henrik - stop hurting Monica Apologies, please see edited post above.

Comment: Wouldn’t $x^2y$ and $\frac{xy^2}{2}$ work?

Comment: @Harshal Gajjar Thanks! But could you explain how I could go about deriving those functions? Is it just trial and error? Because I have a couple of area integrals to integrate for a variety of functions, so I need to know how I can derive the respective $P$ and $Q$ for each.

Comment: Write the expression as sum of two non zero terms and then integrate those terms, for instance, here: $xy = 2xy -xy$. There might be a better method though.

Comment: The best choice of $P$ and $Q$ will depend on the exact polygon, is one provided in the problem?